# Copy file from app installation folder to Local storage

Tags: c#, windows

I'm attempting to copy a file from the installed location of my Windows 8 app to it's local storage. I've been researching around and trying to do this to no avail. This is what I have come up with so far but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
    private async void TransferToStorage()
    {


        try
        {
            // Get file from appx install folder
            Windows.ApplicationModel.Package package = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current;
            Windows.Storage.StorageFolder installedLocation = package.InstalledLocation;
            StorageFile temp1 = await installedLocation.GetFileAsync("track.xml");
            // Read the file
            var lines = await FileIO.ReadLinesAsync(temp1);

            //Create the file in local storage
            StorageFile myStorageFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync("track_iso.xml", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
            // Write to it
            await FileIO.WriteLinesAsync(myStorageFile, lines);

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

        }

    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Just curious, but what was the purpose of needing to do this?

Comment: @A.R. e.g. I have an XML config file template that I want to transfer to local storage so I can modify it.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to update / add a comment.  I found out shortly after asking my question why I would want to.  I have a default settings file that I include with the installation, and then copy to local for saving new settings, etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it myself. Here is the method for anyone else that encounters this question / problem:

```
   private async void TransferToStorage()
    {
        // Has the file been copied already?
        try
        {
            await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("localfile.xml");
            // No exception means it exists
            return;
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
        {
            // The file obviously doesn't exist

        }
        // Cant await inside catch, but this works anyway
        StorageFile stopfile = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///installfile.xml"));
        await stopfile.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

No reason to read all the lines and write it to another file. Just use [File.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).