# UWP app: How can I deploy updatable Json file?

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps

How can I package a json file with my Win10  app so that it appears as an independent file in the LocalState (or sub) folder?   I need for my app to be able to update this file occasionally.

If this is impossible can the app place files in some app data folder during the install?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26944399/318501

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can mark that file as "Content" and "Copy Always" and on app start-up, you can copy that to LocalFolder programmatically and then update it whenever you want.

For example: Let's say you have a "Config" folder under root project and test.json is the file you want to replace then

```
string testPath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "test.json");

if (!File.Exists(testPath))
    {
            string tempPath = "ms-appx:///Config/test.json";
            Uri location = new Uri(tempPath, UriKind.Absolute);
            StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(location);
            await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer; couldn't find this type of info anywhere in Microsoft documentation

Answer (score 2):

Just copy it from the app package to the app local storage at first run.

Comment: I added it to VS and set to CopyAlways but it doesn't show up.